# When is the infinite union of compact sets a compact set?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We know that in general the union of infinitely many compact sets is not a compact set, however it is possible to have some cases in which the union is compact. Is there any study about these cases? I tried to find some information but I couldn't find anything. I'd like some characterization of these unions that determines under which circumstances it is compact. Anything on any space is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If one of the sets contains all others e.g. Any compact set is the union of its finite subsets. These are examples of trivial cases. IMHO we cannot really say something interesting here.

Comment: Oh yes yes, thank you @HennoBrandsma! I'm wondering if we can get some more sophisticated cases.

Comment: You could work in hyperspaces  and find topological criteria there. Maybe the union of Cauchy sequence of compact sets is compact?

Comment: This idea is very good, I'll take a look, thanks again @HennoBrandsma . Indeed my question comes from a problem my professor asked while studying the hyperspace of compact sets of a complete metric space and I had to prove that some union was compact in R^n under very specific conditions. Right now I'm writing everything down together to check if isn't there any error. I think that this hyperspace theory is fascinating, although I don't have much contact with it yet.

Comment: If $K(X)$ denotes the hyperspace of compact subsets of $X$ and $\mathcal K \subset K(X)$ is compact then $\bigcup \mathcal K$ is a compact subset of $X$.

Comment: Hmmm do you have any reference on it so I can take a look @timon92 ?

Comment: @Bryant A. Kechris, Classical descriptive set theory, Exercise 4.29 v)